# How to find the best fixed effect in a mixed model?

Tags: r, anova, mixed-model

I am trying to see the difference between two variables in mixed models.

**Background:** The models are for an experiment with a randomized complete block design, but there is a bit of missing data. Yield is being estimated by the fixed effect of 31 different treatments with 1 to 3 replicates in 4 blocks. The additional fixed effects that I am trying to sort through measure several parameters of each treatment (height, diameter, width, height_2--a different method of measuring height--, etc). My basic model starts with the following formula `yield ~ Treatment + (Treatment:Block)` using the `lme4` function `lmer` in R. I removed the block effect and am only including the interaction because when the models got more complicated I was warned of singular fits, and one of the suggestions I read about on how to deal with that was to simplify the model. I should probably have deleted the interaction and kept only the block effect, but this is beside the point for my question here.

**Problem**

My problem comes from when I am comparing two models like the following,

1. `a <- lmer(yield ~ Treatment + (1|Treatment:Block) + height, data=df)`
2. `b <- lmer(yield ~ Treatment + (1|Treatment:Block) + height_2, data=df)`

I want to know if one effect (height or height_2) explain yield better when controlling for treatment and block effects. When I run `anova(a,b)` the models are refit to ML instead of REML (which is typical), and the table shows Chi Df of 0 and a Pr(>Chisq) of 1. I don't think I am doing this appropriately.
[image]

I read somewhere that to see if fixed effects are different make a model including both and another similar model but include an interaction of the two effects like below. From the `anova(c,d)` I should know whether the variables (height and height_2) have different effects on yield...(I think)

- . `c <- lmer(yield ~ Treatment + (1|Treatment:Block) + height + height_2,
  data=df)`
- . `d <- lmer(yield ~ Treatment + (1|Treatment:Block) + height + height_2 + (height:height_2), data=df)`

Is the purpose of the previous comparison correct as I wrote it?

I still need to know: How to test whether one variable is a better predictor compared to the other if my first method is incorrect?

Bonus question: Are my variables (all or some) crossed or nested? Am I coding them correctly in `lmer()`... I read the answer to this [question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/228800/crossed-vs-nested-random-effects-how-do-they-differ-and-how-are-they-specified) and I am still a bit fuzzy on how it applies to my situation.

Comment: Why do you have treatment as a random effect? I would think you should only have Block as fixed effect.

Comment: I have not intended to have treatment as a random effect. Does it become random as a result of the interaction term? The situation is that the treatments acted differently in different Blocks and I need to control for that treatment effect before I can look at the other parameters. When more than 2 of the fixed parameters were added I ran into the singular fit issues and block by itself didn't improve the model, but the interaction did. Why do you say to have only block as a fixed effect?

Comment: Oh, if the treatment effects differ between the blocks, that is not so good. In that case I don't know how to analyze the data best.

Comment: Oops, I meant that I thought that the treatment should only be fixed! Apoligies

Answer (score 0):

The first method of comparing the two heights is wrong because the two *models* are not nested as anova requires. Instead you can just compare the likelihood values of the two models and choose the height variable that produces the highest likelihood (which is equivalent to AIC here because the two models have the same number of free parameters). In your dataset, model A has a higher likelihood (-727.1 compared to -752.7), meaning that height predicts the yield better than heigjt_2.

The second method you suggest compares the height variables by defining a model with both of them and testing if either height variables can be removed from the model (hope I understood that correctly). That is okay, but it can be inconclusive if both of them can be removed from model.

Comment: Are you suggesting I do `ab_compare<-anova(a,b)` then only look at `ab_compare$logLik` for comparing? If not then how do I get the likelihood value? If yes then how come the likelihood of `ab_compare` is correct without having the two models nested correctly?

Comment: Yes that you can do. Anova tries to calculate the chisquare likelihood ratio tests between the two models, and that it can't do because the models are not nested. Anova also reports the likelihood values and yes, those you can use to compare the models even though the models are not nested. (I wrote that the anova was wrong because the chisquare test was impossible)

Comment: How could I compare whether the differences in log likelihood are "significant" through some sort of p<0.05 approach?

Comment: It is not really possible to get a P value for the comparison here